# Get all documents in a mongodb aggregation pipeline containing a $limit stage

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am using `mongodb 3.4`.

In my application, I have an aggregation operation with a `$limit` stage.
Now I want to know how I can get all records from the pipeline, ignoring the `$limit`. Removing `$limit` is not feasible because I need all records only in a specific scenario.

In the mongodb `find()` operation, I know I can bypass the `cursor.limit()` operation by passing 0 as the limit, and I'm looking for something similar for aggregation `$limit`.